# Display data on selected item with Laravel and Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm trying to display the selected data from table to a modal using Ajax but seems no working. I used the restful routing in laravel. Data is successfully fetched but I'm stuck in displaying it inside the modal.

Controller:

```
public function show($project)
{
    $project = Project::find($project);
    return \Response::json($project);
}
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        $("#editProject").modal('show');
        $('#editProject').find('.modal-body').html(data);
    }
})
```

From console:

[image]

Comment: your modal is only an element which has an ID or a class, so I think that would suffice to display your data in the modal.

Comment: yeah, I have the data now in json format and how can I display it in my modal body? I t ried using `$project->id`... bu no luck

Comment: can you show the output of your console.log and how are you passing this value to the modal element/s?

Comment: @Roljhon, I already updated my post. Kindly check. Thanks

Comment: have you tried parsing your JSON first before displaying and is your `find()` function returned the element `modal-body` successfully?

Comment: @Roljhon, I think no need to parse it since I get the exact sting

Comment: Yes, it returned the modal body but no content even the html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137228/discussion-between-roljhon-and-claudios).